# Locate string using RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy and stamp an image using iTextSharp's PDFstamper. Problem stamping all locations

Tags: regex, vb.net, pdf, itext

I am trying to locate a string pattern in a PDF using Itext7's RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy looping through all the pages in said PDF.  The string for instance that I am searching for is "Conrad Noll IV, #6272795".  What I am trying to do is that every time I find the x and 7 coordinates of this string, I use those coordinates, subtracting a few points from the x coordinate so that I can stamp an "X" (png image) next to it.

Here is my code/module of what I have tried.

```vb
    Imports iTextSharp.text
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.IO.Path
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
    Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser
    Imports System.Linq
    Imports iText
    Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener
    Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser
    Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf

    Module Module1
    Dim signedFolder = "C:\Users\xborja\Desktop\Original PDF's\Signed PDFs\"
    Sub Main()

    If Not Directory.Exists(signedFolder) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(signedFolder)
    End If
    Dim src = "C:\Users\xborja\Desktop\Original PDF's Before Merge\TP067389.CRUZ.pdf"
    Dim pattern = "Conrad Noll IV, #6272795"
    Dim inputfile As Stream = New FileStream(src, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Dim inputImage As Stream = New FileStream("C:\Users\user\source\repos\addImagePdf\addImagePdf\CN signature.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Dim xmarkImage As Stream = New FileStream("C:\Users\user\Desktop\xmark.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Dim finalPDF As String = signedFolder & GetFileNameWithoutExtension(src) & " signed.pdf"
    Dim outputPdf As Stream = New FileStream(finalPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    Dim pdfReader = New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(src)
    Dim pdfReader2 = New pdf.PdfReader(inputfile)
    Dim pdfDoc As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument = New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader)
    Dim pageCount = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages
    Dim pagecount2 = pdfReader2.NumberOfPages
    Dim extractionStrategy As RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy = New RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy(pattern)
    Dim locationList As IList(Of IPdfTextLocation) = New List(Of IPdfTextLocation)
    Dim parser As PdfCanvasProcessor = New PdfCanvasProcessor(extractionStrategy)

    Dim stamper = New pdf.PdfStamper(pdfReader2, outputPdf)

    Dim pdfContentByte = Nothing
    Dim image As Image = Image.GetInstance(inputImage)
    Dim xmark As Image = Image.GetInstance(xmarkImage)

    Dim xy = Nothing
    Dim counter = 0

    Console.WriteLine(pagecount2)

    For page1 = 1 To pagecount2

        parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetPage(page1)) ' THIS has to be outside the for each
        For Each location As IPdfTextLocation In extractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations
            parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetPage(page1))
            pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(page1)
            If location IsNot Nothing Then
                counter += 1
                Dim xP = Math.Round(location.GetRectangle.GetX)
                Dim yP = Math.Round(location.GetRectangle.GetY)


                xmark.SetAbsolutePosition(xP - 18, yP)
                pdfContentByte.addimage(xmark)
                stamper.Close()

                Console.WriteLine(pattern & " " & xP & " " & yP & " located on page " & page1 & " and counter is " & counter)

            End If

        Next location

    Next page1

End Sub

End Module
```

As you can see I am using 2 different readers in tandem with each other because each reader has different parameters it takes so I tried doing something tricky by using a combination of both.

When I run this and print out to myself the results it shows the correct amount of X and Y positions for the string I was searching and the correct number of pages but the itextsharp.pdfstamper only stamps ONE location, which is the first location it found.

The xmark.SetAbsolutePosition(xP - 18, yP) is what I am setting so that when it finds the x y coordinates, the x is subtracting by 8 thus moving my X image directly to the right of it so it looks like the name was checked out.

Is there a reason why the code would read all pages, print out all the locations of searched string, but only stamp one of them?

Answer (score 1):

You close the `PdfStamper` inside the inner loop after adding the mark:

```
For page1 = 1 To pagecount2
    ...
    For Each location As IPdfTextLocation In extractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations
        ...
        If location IsNot Nothing Then
            ...
            xmark.SetAbsolutePosition(xP - 18, yP)
            pdfContentByte.addimage(xmark)
            stamper.Close()
            ...
        End If
    Next location
Next page1
```

Thus, after the first mark is added, the stamper finalizes its output and then accepts no changes anymore. Move that `Close` call after the loops:

```
For page1 = 1 To pagecount2
    ...
    For Each location As IPdfTextLocation In extractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations
        ...
        If location IsNot Nothing Then
            ...
            xmark.SetAbsolutePosition(xP - 18, yP)
            pdfContentByte.addimage(xmark)
            ' stamper.Close()
            ...
        End If
    Next location
Next page1
stamper.Close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could keep everything within Itext and not use itextsharp and use this code instead:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Path
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser
Imports System.Linq
Imports iText
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf
Imports iText.Layout
Imports iText.IO.Image
Imports iText.Layout.Element
Imports iText.Layout.Properties

Module Module1
    Dim signedFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\Original PDF's\Signed PDFs\"
    Sub Main()

        If Not Directory.Exists(signedFolder) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(signedFolder)
        End If
        Dim src = "C:\Users\Desktop\Original PDF's Before Merge\TP067389.CRUZ.pdf"
        Dim pattern = "Conrad Noll IV, #6272795"

        Dim xmarkImage = "C:\Users\Desktop\xmark.png"
        Dim finalPDF As String = signedFolder & GetFileNameWithoutExtension(src) & " signed.pdf"

        Dim pdfDoc As PdfDocument = New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(New PdfReader(src), New PdfWriter(finalPDF))
        Dim document As Document = New Document(pdfDoc)


        Dim pageCount = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages


        Dim extractionStrategy As RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy = New RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy(pattern)
        Dim locationList As IList(Of IPdfTextLocation) = New List(Of IPdfTextLocation)
        Dim parser As PdfCanvasProcessor = New PdfCanvasProcessor(extractionStrategy)

        Dim xmark As ImageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(xmarkImage)

        Dim counter = 0

        Dim xp = Nothing
        Dim yp = Nothing


        For page1 = 1 To pageCount

            parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetPage(page1))

            For Each location As IPdfTextLocation In extractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations
                parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetPage(page1))
                If location IsNot Nothing Then
                    counter += 1

                    xp = CType(Math.Round(location.GetRectangle.GetX), Single)
                    yp = CType(Math.Round(location.GetRectangle.GetY), Single)

                    Dim xmimage As Image = New Image(xmark).SetFixedPosition(page1, xp - 16, yp)
                    document.Add(xmimage)

                    locationList.Add(location)
                    Console.WriteLine(pattern & " " & xp & " " & yp & " located on page " & page1)



                End If
            Next location
        Next page1
        document.Close()






    End Sub


End Module
```